# Unable to build project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I imported a project into Android Studio from Eclipse. It was building successfully in Eclipse. 
At the end of importing process I got this error:

```
Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work
```

In the Gradle console I get the following error:

```
Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+
```

I have already installed google support repository as mentioned in other places.

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.entujn.demo"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-   rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar')
}
```

local.properties:

```
sdk.dir=/home/pankaj/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk
```

SDK directory structure [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-esql9qpq7HLWpGem05bUNJQkk/view)

Looks like the appcompat stuff is not present at the right place, how do I fix it ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html  did u review ??

Comment: I did. As I mentioned I was able to build the project in eclipse. The project had a dependency on support libraries. So I believe support libraries were all installed correctly. I expected Android studio to handle all the setup while importing.

Comment: Nope. Stuck with eclipse for the time being. Will try again once I am through with current work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Android Studio uses another copy of SDK, which does not have Android Support repository installed. Please make sure it has all needed components installed.

Comment: How do I find where another copy is located? And how do I ensure I install the support repository there ?

Comment: the older versions of studio had thier sdk inside thier own directory. so it is: /path/to/android-studio/sdk

Comment: with one of the last 2 or 3 updates you had to move the sdk out of the android studio path.

Comment: Select you project in the Project Explorer, press F4 (Project Structure), here you can find SDK location.

Comment: I checked in project explorer, it shows the proper sdk location (the one used with eclipse). So probably there is no other copy ..some other problem then?

Comment: Can you confirm Android Support Repository and Android Support Library are installed there? Try Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager and check it.

Comment: If you see the screenshot , you can clearly see the m2repository directory there. Support library is also there because it was compiling fine in eclipse. In any case I am going back to eclipse for the time being. Already wasted lot of time in experimentation :-(

Comment: You're requesting a specific version of the support library. Just because the m2 repository is there doesn't mean you have that version of it. SDK manager will tell what version you have installed.